# Fastest way to get a cumulative list in pandas DataFrame with multi-index, grouped by index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

So I have a data frame that looks like

```
                    column
index1    index2 
0         0             10
          1             11
          2             12
          3             13
          4             14
1         0             20
          1             21
          2             22
          3             23
          4             24
```

and I want to obtain a dataframe that looks like

```
                    column          cumulative
index1    index2 
0         0             10                  []
          1             11                [10]
          2             12            [10, 11]
          3             13        [10, 11, 12]
          4             14    [10, 11, 12, 13]
1         0             20                  []
          1             21                [20]
          2             22            [20, 21]
          3             23        [20, 21, 22]
          4             24    [20, 21, 22, 23]
```

I'm guaranteed that the indices are sorted. I'm also fine if the objects that I'm storing in the `cumulative` column aren't Python lists and instead Numpy arrays if that makes the implementation more efficient.

Basically the goal is to use the full history of the outcomes of a feature as itself another feature in some machine-learning algorithm. If this is not a recommended way to do this, then please suggest another way.

Answer (score 2):

May be not the most elegant:

```
df.assign(column=df['column'].apply(lambda x: [x])).groupby(level=0).apply(np.cumsum)
```

---

```
                             column
index1 index2                      
0      0                       [10]
       1                   [10, 11]
       2               [10, 11, 12]
       3           [10, 11, 12, 13]
       4       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
1      0                       [20]
       1                   [20, 21]
       2               [20, 21, 22]
       3           [20, 21, 22, 23]
       4       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

Comment: exactly what I was thinking of.

Comment: @Anonymous `apply(lambda x: [x]` turns each element into list. Then I grouped on the first index or level=0 , and applied [`np.cumsum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) on it which returns a summed list

Comment: Hmm ok. Is this really the fastest solution though? Is it possible to make it faster by doing column-wise operations rather than using `apply` which goes row-by-row? Also, does the create of a lot of list objects (probably on the scale of about ~100,000 lists, where each list has about ~100 elements) hinder the speed significantly? Would it be faster to use numpy arrays?

Comment: @Anonymous i donot know of a better way. you can wait and see if you get a vectorized version